# Split Array with ActionScript

Tags: arrays, actionscript, split, actionscript-2

Quick Array question for someone...  So I have this array:

```
var bodyText:Array = ["1||^^1a::##1b||1", "2||^^2a::##2b||2"];
```

And I need to parse and format it like so:

Question: 1
Correct Answer: 1a
Incorrect Answer: 1b
Feedback: 1

Question: 2
Correct Answer: 2a
Incorrect Answer: 2b
Feedback: 2

I'm pretty close to a solution but for whatever reason I'm having issues with the correct/incorrect keys, for instance, this what my code traces:

```
Question: 1
Correct Answer: 1a
^^1a
##1b
Incorrect Answer: 1b
Feedback: 1

Question: 2
Correct Answer: 2a
^^2a
##2b
Incorrect Answer: 2b
Feedback: 2
```

Here is my script, any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

```
var bodyText:Array = ["1||^^1a::##1b||1", "2||^^2a::##2b||2"];
var _txt:String;
for (var i:Number = 0; i < bodyText.length; i++) {
    var _tb:Array = bodyText[i].split("||");
    for (var j:Number = 0; j < _tb.length; j++) {
        //question
        _txt = "Question: " + _tb[0] + "\n";

        //answers
        var _kb:Array = _tb[1].split("::");
        for (var k:Number = 0; k < _kb.length; k++) {
            _txt += _kb[k].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
            _txt += _kb[k].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";
        }

        //feedback
        _txt += "Feedback: " + _tb[2] + "\n";
    }
    trace(_txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

```
var bodyText:Array = ["1||^^1a::##1b||1", "2||^^2a::##2b::##2c||2"];
var _txt:String;
for (var i:Number = 0; i < bodyText.length; i++) {
    var _tb:Array = bodyText[i].split("||");
    for (var j:Number = 0; j < _tb.length; j++) {
        //Question:
        _txt = "Question: " + _tb[0] + "\n";

        //Answers:
        var _kb:Array = _tb[1].split("::");
        for (var k:Number = 0; k < _kb.length; k++) {
            if (_kb[k].indexOf("^^") != -1) {
                _txt += _kb[k].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
            } else {
                _txt += _kb[k].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";
            }
        }
        //Feedback:
        _txt += "Feedback: " + _tb[2] + "\n";
    }
    trace(_txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_txt += _kb[0].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
_txt += _kb[1].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";
```

If each question has only one correct answer and one incorrect answer the above should suffice.

The reason you are getting the `^^1a` is because of how you are splitting

```
for (var k:Number = 0; k < _kb.length; k++) {
            _txt += _kb[k].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
            _txt += _kb[k].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";
        }
```

This line

```
_kb[k].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
```

replaces the `^^` for kb[0]
but the second line

```
_txt += _kb[k].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";
```

does not find `##` and returns `^^1a`

on the next iteration it will be the reverse, k is now 1 : `##1b`

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop is unnecessary, see the code below (tried it, worked):

```
var bodyText:Array = ["1||^^1a::##1b||1", "2||^^2a::##2b||2"];
            var _txt:String;
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < bodyText.length; i++) {
                var _tb:Array = bodyText[i].split("||");
                for (var j:Number = 0; j < _tb.length; j++) {
                    //question
                    _txt = "Question: " + _tb[0] + "\n";

                    //answers
                    var _kb:Array = _tb[1].split("::");
                    _txt += _kb[0].split("^^").join("Correct Answer: ") + "\n";
                    _txt += _kb[1].split("##").join("Incorrect Answer: ") + "\n";

                    //feedback
                    _txt += "Feedback: " + _tb[2] + "\n";
                }
                trace(_txt);
            }
```

Cheers,
Rob